# Can we implement AOP with or without Spring in AEM 6.x?

Tags: spring, aem, spring-aop, aem-6

We need to add some detailed level of logging in or AEM Models, Servlets and Services.

I wanted to know if we can do thing by implementing custom AOP in AEM or by using Spring AOP within AEM.

Does anyone have experience working on this?

PS: For those of you who don't know, AEM stands for Adobe Experience Manger a Java based CMS.

Comment: Maybe AspectJ will be better?

Comment: Question is how to I implement it within my framework?
Is spring pluggable into every other Java based framework ?

Comment: AspectJ is separated library. Add it as dependency and use by tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just should have used your favourite web search engine.

- AspectJ != Spring AOP
- AspectJ is completely independent of any framework and can be used in any POJO Java SE application as well as in any container. I.e. you don't need Spring.
- You have a choice between

  - compile-time weaving,
  - post-compile-time weaving (existing class files and JARs),
  - load-time weaving (Java agent applies instrumentation dynamically during class-loading).

Just make your choice and maybe learn some AspectJ basics.

Comment: Sounds promising, I did look for AspectJ implementations with my framework which is build on OSGi. My favourite  search engine didn't help me that much. May be you can give me start of how to implement AspectJ into OSGi frameworks ?

Comment: Just use compile-time weaving, if applicable. Then there is no need to worry about OSGi. Only if you want your aspects to affect third-party code outside the control of your compiler, you would need to worry about how to get load-time weaving working in all those isolated class loaders. I am not an OSGi guy and have zero experience with it, but I remember questions about it on the AspectJ mailing list and you might also find something here on SO. The feature to [attach the weaving agent during runtime](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/README-187.html) might help you there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this documentation:
http://www.tothenew.com/blog/integrating-spring-aop-with-aem/

And make sure that you have the AspectJ Service Mix bundle installed on your AEM.
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.servicemix.bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.aspectj/1.9.4_1

HTH.